# NoMethodError in ConfirmationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been trying to solve the following problem for a couple of days. Forgive me if this is a common problem as I am new to rails and probably couldn't query the right question/keyword in stackoverflow or google.

I am building a system where a user will get an invite via email, click on a unique link, be taken to a page where he/she can accept or decline the invitation. I am getting stuck at the part where the user accepts or declines the invitation.

I've built it around two controllers: an invitations controller and a confirmations controller.The invitations controller creates a record containing a name, an email, and a uniquely generated token. The controller then emails a link with the token to the defined email. The link points to the confirmations controller and passes the unique token from the invitation. However, when clicking on the link and accepting the invitation, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in ConfirmationController#confirm
undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is some of the code for solving this issue:

Confirmation_controller.rb

```
class ConfirmationController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @confirmation = Invitation.find_by_invite_token(params[:invite_token])
    end

    def confirm
      if @confirmation.update_attribute(:accepted, true) 
         flash[:success] = "Invitation confirmed!"
         redirect_to 'static_pages/home'
      else
         flash[:notice] = "Failed :("
         redirect_to 'static_pages/home'
      end
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
match '/confirmation/:invite_token', to: 'confirmation#new'
match '/confirmation/:invite_token/confirm', to: 'confirmation#confirm'
```

app/views/confirmation/new.html.erb

```
Click here to accept:
<%= link_to "Confirm", :controller => "confirmation", :action => "confirm" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get your `Invitation` in the `confirm` method too.

If you want rails to raise an exception if no invitation was found

```
def confirm
  @confirmation = Invitation.find_by_invite_token!(params[:invite_token])
  @confirmation.update_...
end
```

No exception will be raise. You may want to check manually with a condition in the following case.

```
def confirm
  @confirmation = Invitation.find_by_invite_token(params[:invite_token])
  if @confirmation
    @confirmation.update_...
  else
    # do something
  end
end
```

Comment: What happens if the invitation isn't found? Ideally there should first be a check to see if the confirmation record was found THEN do an update.

Comment: `find_by_invite_token` should raise an exception

Comment: No, it should not. It just returns `nil`. To make it throw exeption, you should use `find_by_invite_token!`.

Comment: This worked in updating the record, however, once I click Confirm in my view, the database gets updated appropriately but, I get the following error in Chrome: 

`No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.`

Comment: Figured it out. For some reason, I had to change `redirect_to` to `render`

Comment: `redirect_to` as the its name, will redirect the client to some given URL. `render` will simply render an html page. For more information on the two, please read here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

You should find `confirmation` record before calling `update_attribute` on it, like you did it in `new` action:

```
@confirmation = Invitation.find_by_invite_token(params[:invite_token])
```

Or, to throw exception when the record is not found and to render 404 page to the user:

```
@ocnfirmation = Invitation.find_by_invite_token!(params[:invite_token])
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this did the trick. However, once I click Confirm in my view, the database gets updated appropriately but, I get the following error in Chrome: 

`No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never told the program what @confirmation is. What you should do is find it first then run the update. Note this is different from the different answers, just thought I would throw in some variety.

```
def confirm
  # You're missing this line below. Basic search for the confirmation.
  # Note too that you will have to pass in the parameter `invite_token` for it to work
  # I'm also assuming invite_token is unique among each invitation 
  confirmation = Invitation.where(invite_token: params[:invite_token])

  # Notice that I'm first checking to see if the confirmation record exists, then doing an update
  if confirmation and confirmation.update_attribute(:accepted, true) 
     flash[:success] = "Invitation confirmed!"
     redirect_to 'static_pages/home'
  else
     flash[:notice] = "Failed :("
     redirect_to 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Even though there will always be an invite_token, I guess it is best to explicitly check for it again?